# Xcode 7 code coverage reporting not working

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm

I'm having problems to get code coverage reporting working in Xcode 7 for a certain iOS project.

I'm following the instructions given here:
http://mgrebenets.github.io/mobile%20ci/2015/09/21/code-coverage-for-ios-xcode-7/

Of the three projects I tried, two are working fine, but one project is giving me a headache. When using llvm-cov utility to generate a report from the gathered profile data like this:

```
xcrun llvm-cov report -instr-profile Coverage.profdata MyAppBinary
```

I receive the error message:

```
error: Failed to load coverage: The file was not recognized as a valid object file
```

I checked that the "Gather coverage data" is enabled for the Test scheme. I also checked that the -fprofile-instr-generate and -fcoverage-mapping compiler options are passed to clang.

File sizes and types also look valid to me:

```
ilMac:llvm-cov-test ilja$ ls -la
total 61976
drwxr-xr-x   4 ilja  staff       136 14 Okt 21:53 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 75 ilja  staff      2550 14 Okt 16:31 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 ilja  staff   1797416 14 Okt 21:53 Coverage.profdata
-rwxr-xr-x   1 ilja  staff  29932040 14 Okt 16:32 MyAppBinary

ilMac:llvm-cov-test ilja$ file Coverage.profdata 
Coverage.profdata: data

ilMac:llvm-cov-test ilja$ file MyAppBinary 
MyAppBinary: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
MyAppBinary (for architecture i386):    Mach-O executable i386
MyAppBinary (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

I also noted that the "Coverage" tab in Xcode for the Test run is saying "No coverage data" instead of the indicator bars.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: i'm trying to follow same article and have same error. Have you solve this problem ? If yes could please help me ? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Posting my solution in case someone will need it. 
Following this article [code coverage xcode 7](http://mgrebenets.github.io/mobile%20ci/2015/09/21/code-coverage-for-ios-xcode-7)
I did following steps:

1. Installed cobertura plugin
2. Installed slather plugin
3. Enabled code coverage for project (in schema preferences)
4. In jenkins added execute shell command

`/usr/bin/xcodebuild test -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyAppTests -configuration DebugMyApp -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,OS=9.3,name=iPhone 6" -enableCodeCoverage YES`

5. Then one more build stem for slather

`slather coverage \
    --input-format profdata \
    --cobertura-xml \
    --ignore "../**/*/Xcode*" \
    --output-directory slather-report \
    --scheme MyAppTests \
    --workspace MyApp.xcworkspace \
    MyApp.xcodeproj`

6. And last but no least add post build step "publich cobertura report"
   Cobertura xml report pattern - slather-report/cobertura.xml
7. Enjoy :)

Comment: Any help if i don't want to use *slather* for code coverage ?

Answer (score 0):

The project had the "Build Active Architecture Only" setting in the Xcode build settings set to "YES". After switching it to "NO", I can now run the llvm-cov command. Numbers don't macht the numbers displayed in Xcode, though.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by running with only `x86_64` architecture.

Use `ARCHS="x86_64"` `VALID_ARCHS="x86_64"` in your `xcodebuild` command